# Docker stop sleeping bash script

Tags: linux, bash, docker, sh

I have bash script which runs as docker entrypoint.

This script does some things and then sleeps.

I need to be able to gracefully stop this script when `docker stop` command is issued. AFAIK docker sends `SIGTERM` signal to the process 1.

So I created bash script which reacts to `SIGTERM`.

It works fine without docker, I can launch it, issue `kill -TERM <pid>` and it gracefully stops the script. Unfortunately it does not work in docker.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /root
COPY test.sh .
CMD ./test.sh
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo TERM; exit' TERM

sleep 1 &
while wait $!
do
    sleep 1 &
done
```

How should I modify script or Dockerfile to allow docker stop to work without issues?

Please note that I'm not allowed to pass `-it` argument to `docker run`.

Comment: Not a Bash script, it's executed by `/bin/sh` which is a POSIX shell, not Bash.

Comment: What is the container supposed to actually be doing?  Can you delete the sleep loop, and just let the container exit when its main process completes?  (Consider also launching the container with the `docker run --rm` option so it deletes itself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from *the shell form* of the `CMD` instruction: `CMD ./test.sh`.

In this case the command is executed with a `/bin/sh -c` shell. So the `/bin/sh` runs as `PID 1` and then forks `test.sh`, `PID 1` is `/bin/sh -c ./test.sh`. In consequence the `SIGTERM` signal is sent to the `PID 1` and never reaches `test.sh`.

To change this you have to use the *exec form*: `CMD ["./test.sh"]`. In this case, the command will be executed **without a shell**. So the signal will reach your script.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /root
COPY test.sh .
CMD ["./test.sh"]
```

Run and kill.

```sh
# run
docker run -d --name trap trap:latest
# send the signal
docker kill --signal=TERM trap
# check if the signal has been received
docker logs trap
# TERM
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try with `docker kill --signal=SIGTERM <CONTAINER_ID>`.

Please let me know if it will work.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, unfortunately nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Note if your script happens to spawn child process, you may leave behind orphan process upon your docker exit. Try run with **--init** flag like `docker run --init ...`, the built-in docker-init executable `tini` will assumed pid 1 and ensure all child process (such as your sleep example) will be terminated accordingly upon exit.